# Is it possible to transfer a world from iPad to PS4?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios, minecraft-legacy-console

How do I transfer my Minecraft world from an iPad Air to a PlayStation 4?

Answer (score 1):

Saving world:

1. Go on your iPad to the ‘Files’ app.
2. Go to ‘on my iPad’.
3. Go to minecraft -> Games -> .commojang -> minecraft worlds.
4. Look into the different world files, there should be one with the world icon of your world. There is no name because the worlds are saved by code for example: `2dIn7Ro9`.
5. Copy the world file to your iCloud.
6. Open iCloud on a pc or something.
7. Copy the iCloud file to the pc. Your world is now saved on your pc

Importing:

1. Gets the PS4 USB and plug it into your computer (if it fits).
2. Copy the file onto your USB.
3. Go on your PS4 to settings
4. Go to Application Saved Data management
5. Close any games that are open
6. Go to Saved Data on USB. storage.
7. Click to copy the USB storage.
8. Click on Minecraft.
9. Click on all files to successfully copy.

Answer (score 0):

(Please note, I do not own a ps4 but this is how you do it to add worlds to an Xbox)

---

The files of Minecraft can be accessed by any computer that is connected with a lightning/usb cable and has iTunes installed. From there go into iTunes on your computer, there will be an button with an iPad on it, click that and scroll down. There will be a panel on the side called file sharing, where you will be able to to transfer files. Transfer the files then go to Minecraft/games/com.mojang/Minecraft worlds from there you will be able to access all your world files. Now connect you pc to your console and you will be able to transfer the .mcworld file to the console. Run the .mcworld and it will automatically add itself to your Minecraft game. Then just open the game and select the save.